# which is best between string isEmpty and StringUtils.isNotBlank()

Tags: java, string, string-utils

I use the following code to check timing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String foo = "foo";
    long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(foo));
    long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("isBlank="+(end-start));
    start=System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (foo!=null && !foo.isEmpty());
    end=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Sec="+(end-start));
}
```

The StringUtils.isBlank() method takes 3ms longer than a simple String.isEmpty() method. Which method should we use?

Comment: does this 3ms differences cause any impact on the performance of your application? do you have that verified using a profiler?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java.

Comment: we used StringUtils.isBlank() method approx 15 times in a single method.

Answer (score 7):

```
StringUtils.isBlank(foo));
```

Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

[StringUtils.isBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29)

```
foo.isEmpty()
```

Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

[isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

So if want something advanced like which will not throw NPE if string is null, ignore the empty string (so auto trim ) then use `StringUtils.isBlank(foo));`

On the other hand as you shown the performance difference which have a very good cause to be `isEmpty()` just see the length.

Its your choice depending on the need.